# Rename file before unlocking PDF with ghostscript batch script

Tags: batch-file

**Current behaviour**
I have a batch script that unlocks pdfs with ghostscript. I just have to drop a pdf file via drag-and-drop on the script file to unlock it. It will create an unlocked file in the same folder.

**example:**
I drag-and-drop locked file "datasheet.pdf" onto the script file. It will generate an unlocked file called "datasheet_no.pdf" in the same folder where the "datasheet.pdf" file is.

**I want to modify the NAMING of the files:**
After dropping "datasheet.pdf" onto the script, I want to have a UNprotected "datasheet.pdf" file and the old protected file "datasheet_old.pdf"

I hope someone can help me. I tried out stuff like REN and DEL, but it never works. Or I end up with pdfs with blank pages and losing the old file. I have only little experience with batch. I found this Script via google.

**Working Script which should be modified:**

```
@echo off
echo.
echo.
set PATH="C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin"
echo **************************************
echo.
echo   Start processing, may take a while, please wait.
echo.
echo **************************************
echo.
echo.
set filein=%~1
set fileout=%filein:~0,-4%
set patch=%filein:~0,-4%

gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFPassword= -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dPassThroughJPEGImages=true -sOutputFile="%fileout%_no.pdf" "%~1"
```

Comment: `path` is a variable which contains the sequence of directorynames that windows searches for executables not found in this directory. It shouldn't be varied. Since you have no `setlocal` at the start of the file, any changes made to environment variables will remain for the duration in that `cmd` instance. `patch` is not being used.

Comment: This isn't actualy a question about Ghostscript at all. However, in passing; you are not 'unocking' a PDF file. You are making a brand new one which shouold be visually the same. In particular Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device do not support the PassThroughJPEGImages distiller parameter, so JPEG images will be decompressed and recompressed, with consequent loss of quality. Unless you know exactly what you are doing I would strongly advise against using -dPDFSETTINGS at all.

Comment: @Magoo you are right. I remove 'patch'.

Comment: @KenS Okay, thank you. I didnt know that as I just copied the script from someones webpage. I will remove 'dPassThroughJPEGImages' and 'dPDFSETTINGSSettings' from the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ren "%~1" "%~n1_old%~x1"
ren "%fileout%_no.pdf" "%~nx1"
```

should first rename the original file to *originalname*_old*originalextension* and the *createdoutputfile* to *originalnameandextension*

Note that the *target* name of a `ren` command must *not* include the path to the file.